# Issues with upgrading artifactory from 6.0.2 to 7.29.8

Tags: artifactory

I should upgrade an old artifactory (v6.0.2) server running von centos 7.9 and installed with zip archive.

Since this is a huge gap i tested it on an empty test-setup.
I upgraded from 6.0.2->6.18.0->7.2.0->7.29.8 (i used official documentation for this)
Everything seems to be fine.

Now I got a cloned instance of the actual artifactory serving about 300k artifacts.
I did the same as in my test-setup.
Artifactory is running, i encountered not problems while upgrading.

However, I tested to download some JAR files and some of them work some of them dont.
Also getting some notification that meta data of docker images are missing when i browse the UI.
Another stange thing is that the number of artifacts increased.
So the actual artifactory serving araoudn 300,000 artifacts - the test-setup serves now about 400,000 artifacts.

Where could the mistake be?

I made a mistake on copying the filestore and it wasnt actually copied in migration from 6.18->7.12.

So now I can access the files with no errors.

But why does the new Artifactory still shows 400,000 artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is expected behaviour.
Artifactory 6.6 introduces a new local Build Info repository. This default artifactory-build-info repository will store all build info files uploaded to Artifactory. Your existing builds will be available as part of this repository and which will in turn increase the number of artifacts. Please refer to [this release notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory6.6) for further details.

Also, From Artifactory version Artifactory 6.8 support bundles are moved to a repository which will in turn increase the number of artifacts. Please refer to [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Support+Zone#SupportZone-SupportBundlesRepository) for the details.

Comment: Thank you, i guess thats the solution :) I thought about something like this and also read about the change with the build info repo but didnt connect it.